# Как правильно отделить логику и представление друг от друга?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvc

Когда мы используем например asp.net mvc то там все понятно с организацией приложения. Оно что называется из коробки разрабатывается по правилам MVC - то есть там сразу есть  четкое разделение на модель, вью и контроллер. А как быть с WinForms? Городить всю логику в обработчиках событий не хочется, это не правильно. Выделить в Winforms модель я могу - ей будет моя бизнес логика. А вот с вью и контроллером есть определенные проблемы - система завязана на обработчики событий, через которые происходит изменение вью и получается что вью и контроллер смешиваются в обработчиках событий. Как в этом случае поступить и правильно отделить логику и представление друг от друга?

Comment: @JuniorTwo, я немного дилетантски скажу, потому что тонкостей не знаю, но для реалтаймовых приложений применяется система MVVM.

>  система завязана на обработчики событий, через которые происходит изменение вью и получается что вью и контроллер смешиваются в обработчиках событий.

Чисто формально можно а) повесить два обработчика (вью и контроллера, если событие является application-wide) и б) в обработчиках представления обращаться (тянуть методы) контроллера. Я так понимаю, что здесь на самом деле в том или ином виде реализован пункт Б.

Comment: @JuniorTwo: А почему WinForms? На WPF MVP/MVVM (который не сильно отличается от MVC) реализуется чуть ли не из коробки (за исключением мелких шероховатостей).

Comment: В ВинФормс, как и в асп.нет, используется немного другой, но тем не менее родственный выше указанным паттернам - MVP

Comment: _"А вот с вью и контроллером есть определенные проблемы"_ -- в WinForms контроллер называется Control, который и управляет View. см. ["Как перевести понятия MVP в термины WinForms?"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479865/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-mvp-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-winforms)

Answer (score 2):

Я конечно не являюсь специалистом, а asp.net и в глаза не видел, но попытаюсь помочь чем смогу.
Связь между View и Controller осуществляется по средствам модели "наблюдатель" - т.е. контроллер ловит события из представления. Могу предположить, что так, как прицепляются стандартные методы-обработчики к элементу формы, так же можно прицепить и контроллер. В самом худшем случае можно записать в стандартный метод-обработчик вызов соответствующих методов из контроллера.
У самого проблема из этой же серии в Java Swing - так пока и не понял, как определить какое случилось событие, у какого элемента, какой формы, когда по средствам модели наблюдатель вызвался метод actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) в контроллере.