# Как перевести понятия MVP/MVC в термины WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, шаблоны-проектирования

В [описании паттерна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter) MVP (Model-View-Presenter) сказано следующее:

- Model (Модель) — предоставляет данные для пользовательского интерфейса.
- View (Представление) — реализует отображение данных (Модели) и маршрутизацию пользовательских команд или событий Presenter-у.
- Presenter — управляет Моделью и Представлением. Например извлекает данные из Модели и форматирует их для отображения в Представлении.

Что в WinForms приложениях соответствует View и Presenter?

Answer (score 3):

Стандартная лапша - в code-behind форм в обработчиках событий производится запросы к модели, какая-то работа и визуализация результата.

В mvp модель остается моделью, то есть это набор бизнес-логики, а код в форме делится на View и Presenter

View - это формы, code-behind этих форм, где производится работа по визуальной составляющей, а также туда же сводятся подписки на события контролов

Presenter - туда вынесен рабочий код, который не являются частью визуализации. View содержит ссылку на presenter и вызывает его методы. А presenter содержит ссылку на View через интерфейс

То есть View в обработчиках событий контролов делегирует presenter-у "сделай это", а presenter содержит управляющий код, который опросит модель, получит результат и потом дернет View и скажет ему "отрисуй такое то"

Таким образом визуализирующий и управляющий код разделяются.

По просьбе @Stack привожу пример. Псевдошарпокод.

Имеем простую модель (она же бизнес логика). Просто читает файл планет

```
class PlanetReader{  
    public IList<string> ReadPlanetsFromFile(){
        return File.ReadLines(...)
   }
}
```

Далее интерфейс представления

```
public interface IMainView{
    void ShowPlanets(IList<string> planets);  
}
```

ну и презентер

```
public class Presenter{

    private IMainView _view;

    public Presenter(IMainView view){
      _view=view;
    }            

    public void LoadPlanets(){
        var planets=new PlanetReader().ReadPlanetsFromFile();                        
        _view.ShowPlanets(planets);                                     
    }
}
```

и представление winforms

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMainView{

    private Presenter _presenter;

    public MainForm(){                
      InitializeComponent();          
      button.Click+=OnButtonClick;          
     _presenter=new Presenter(this);
    }         

    public void OnButtonClick(...){
         _presenter.LoadPlanets();
    }


    public void ShowPlanets(IList<string> planets){
       TextBox.Text=string.Join("\n", planets);
    }

}
```

для WPF код в общем то идентичен Winforms кроме класса родителя и сигнатур обработчиков событий (хотя лучше все таки MVVM)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainView
```

для консоли

```
class ConsoleApp : IMainView {

  private Presenter _presenter;

  public ConsoleApp(){
     _presenter=new Presenter(this);
  }                                               

  public void Run(){
     Console.WriteLine("press any key to load planets');
     Console.ReadKey();
     _presenter.LoadPlanets();
  }

  public void ShowPlanets(IList<string> planets){
      Console.WritrLine(string.Join("\n", planets));
  }

}
```

за IMainView может быть скрыто что-угодно - от простой формы winforms до самописной системы отрисовки  на удаленной машине.

Плюшки:

1. "Логика интерфейса" по факту делится на "презентационную логику" и собственно "логику визуализации".
   В "презентационную логику" входит решение, что делать по нажатию на кнопку и что делать с результатом - по сигналу от UI работает с моделью и просит потом "логику визуализации" отобразить результат.
   В "логику визуализации" входит отображение того, что просят - контролы, события, установки полей у контролов, кобминирование контролов и так далее.
2. Презентер не имеет прямой ссылки на представление, поэтому детали отображения на UI инкапсулированы (опять же чистота кода, вся сложность спрятана) и возможность заменять представление на другое.
3. Презентер не имеет прямой ссылки на представление, а значит вместо представлениям можно подсунуть заглушку и протестировать презентер. Тестировать же логику интерфейса без такого разделения крайне сложно (нужно тыкать мышью руками или автоматикой и считывать как то результаты с экрана)

Comment: А Ваш ответ не противоречит тому, что дал Stack?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin конечно противоречит. Я высказал свое (да и не только, я ведь не сам придумал, а в свое время тоже искал ответы) видение паттерна MVP на winforms. А то, что написал он, мне незнакомо и вообще на MVP не похоже

Comment: @vitidev _"код в форме делится на View и Presenter. View - это формы ... подписки на события контролов"_ -- вот это непонятно. для чего делить форму? у всех контролов и у Form базовый класс Control.

Comment: Делят на логические сегменты "отображение" и "управляющий код" дабы не было все в куче. Представление прячется за интерфейсом IView, которому presenter говорит "отобрази это" и конкретная реализация представления (WinForms) с помощью форм(ы) и контролов отображает данные. MVP определяет взаимодействие сегментов приложения (кто о ком знает, с кем и как контактирует), и не предьявляет требований к внутренней реализации сегментов. Можно выбросить WinForms и заменить на что угодно, а для presenter это будет незаметно, ведь он всего лишь знает интерфейс IView.

Comment: @vitidev _" IView, которому presenter говорит "отобрази это" ... выбросить WinForms и заменить на что угодно"_ -- например: строим модель солнечной системы. выводим данные о планетах в таблицу. где можно выбирать строки. т.е. презентер один. прошло время и в модель добавили миллионы астеройдов и т.д. также сделали 3d с сенсорным вводом и т.д. очевидно, презентер придется переделать. я к тому, что презентер `приколочен` к view. а модель (включая логику) должна быть сама по себе для того, чтобы можно было легко менять UI.

Comment: @Stack в winforms проще всего сделать представлением форму (Form), потому что форма является корнем отображения и в нее сходятся подписки на события формы и вложенных в нее контролов. Она и получает интерфейс IView. Это всего лишь удобство, но не требование MVP. Каждая новая форма может рождать свой VP, а может быть в рамках одного IView. Любой кастомный контрол тоже может иметь свой  presenter. Все зависит от ощущений "не делает ли слишком много работы". Но наиболее практично в общем случае - по одному IView на форму.

Comment: @vitidev это все понятно, я про то что presenter неотделим от view. давайте вернемся к примеру. есть программа с информацией о солнечной системе в виде таблицы, где по одной строке на планету. UI в ней может быть даже в console. и у такой программы нет Form и других Control;s. но если мы решим добавить информацию о всех астеройдах, спутниках и т.д. и все это будем выводить в анимированном 3D, с сенсорным вводом, где можно рукой выбрать объекты, то в такой программе будет совершенно другой UI и соответственно свой view и presenter. согласны?

Comment: @Stack паттерн mvp призван решать проблему смешивания кода отображения с логикой. он всего-лишь указывает границы логики и отношения между логическими сегментами. Проблема унификации вида не его задача. Но даже в вашем случае презентер может быть один и один IView, а реализации IView могут быть какими угодно и даже другой UI можно спрятать за реализацией IView. Пример: метод IView::showPlanets(), где в форме будет код который отрисует контролами, а в случае консоли будет класс, который знает как это отобразить в консоли. 3д, сенсор.ввод, ручной выбор - это ВНУТРЕННЕЕ дело представления.

Comment: @vitidev _"паттерн mvp призван решать проблему смешивания кода отображения с логикой"_ -- логика интерфейса и бизнес-логика раные вещи. если не трудно добавьте в свой ответ пример на c#, в котором не меняя Presenter и Model, можно заменить View с WinForms на WPF или ASP.NET

Comment: @Stack MVP (как и другие любые паттерны такого рода) разделяет ответственности, указывает пути коммуникации между частями и позволяет убрать явные зависимости для тестирования. Смена UI всего лишь следствие последнего.  Дополнил ответ примерами.

Answer (score 3):

Решил добавить еще один ответ, потому что размер комментариев ограничен, а у @Stack все перемешалось в голове и мой пост отвечает не на вопрос "как", а на "где и почему?"

Цель MVP не сделать возможность подмены UI (для этого просто нужно менять UI), а разделить ответственности и обеспечить тестируемость.

Допустим нам нужно написать приложение под разные абстрактные платформы.

**у нас разные UI на разных платформах.**

варианты:

- Делаем проект-ядро, где будет логика приложения и создаем по проекту
  UI на каждую платформу и при компиляции оно разберется
- Делаем UI на кроссплатформенных контролах
- *прячем за фасадом (паттерн такой) любые реализации UI приводя их к обобщенному виду фасада. Банально делается класс/интерфейс за которым прячется реальный UI. но это  не MVP, а просто сокрытие сложности и зависимостей*
- *Для подобной же цели служит паттерн "мост". Отличие от варианта с "фасадом", что, вместо сокрытия реализации за фасадом, более ярко выражена связующая шина между приложением и графическим приложением и независимость реализации обоих частей*

**А где же MVP?**

Когда задача подмены UI решена, то нужно реализовать эти самые UI.

Допустим одна из наших UI на WinForms.
В силу особенностей Visual Studio мы получаем на выходе в Code-Behind основной формы кучу методов (евент-хендлеры и кучу приватных методов реализующих логику интерфейса). Мало того, что это лапша кода, так еще все это невозможно тестировать - для тестирования нужно тыкать на кнопки и отслеживать изменение GUI, что сложно.

Возникает желание навести порядок. Это можно сделать 101 способом (MVC/MVP/MVVM/MVVMC/свой вариант), просто некоторые **в конкретном случае** будут менее удобны чем другие, а ведь еще хочется не терять визуальный дизайнер студии. И паттерн MVP хорошо подходит для UI, где нет нормальных биндингов, потому что прост и прячет кучу визуализационного кода за интерфейсом. Это и Winforms, и я вот под андроид тоже использую MVP.

*вообще то это очевидное решение - разделить godobject на классы и удалить зависимости от реализаций, спрятав за интерфейсами. Типичные варианты решений и обозвали паттернами*

Разделив визуализацию и логику мы получаем возможность тестировать ту логику, что вошла в презентер (а туда входит вся управляющая логика взаимодействия с моделью и управления визуализацией). Тестировать просто, ведь презентер просто класс с зависимостями. Если же еще хочется тестировать кнопочки, то winium в руки, но тестировать UI всегда сложно

**"как в вашем примере тестировать Presenter. из-за new в методе LoadPlanets() { var planets=new PlanetReader()...} его невозможно тестировать отдельно от конкретной модели" @Stack**

Для этого используется то, что называется "принцип инверсии зависимостей". *Еще одно очевидное решение, имеющее свое название*

Делаем интерфейс IPlanetReader и выносим его в конструктор. Или же используем ServiceLocator. Или же IoC-контейнеры. Или любой другой вариант. MVP **всего лишь вариант** разделения на ответственности "где за что отвечает", а реализация ответственностей уже не входит в него и там полная свобода действий

---

*тестирование UI это проверка того как смотрятся шрифты* -это вообще тестируется только глазами. мы же говорим про автоматическое тестирование.

Тестирование через эмуляцию нажатий кнопок и считыванием информации с контролов. недостатки: сложность считывания даннных (мало ли какие контролы), сложность изоляции (для проверки, что пользователь существует нам нужно подсунуь базу где пользователь есть), скорость работы (из-за того, что полностью работают все слои приложения). Не выявляет функциональные ошибки, когда делает не то, но показывает правильный результат.

При тестировании презентера можно изолировать и подсунуть любые данные, проверить что идет правильный порядок вызовов модели. Пишется намного проще, есть изоляция и высокая скорость работы. В идеале должно быть больше различных тестов, но выбор необходимых тестов определяется возможностями (тесты бизнесу не нужны. они нужны программисту и за них платить не любят).

Лично мне куда проще тестировать презентер (он выявляет функциональные ошибки и за них мне по шапке дают), а кривизна дизайна не фатальна (вся логика в презентере, в представлении логики практически нет и сломать его сложнее, а вреда от этого минимум).

Comment: _"у @Stack все перемешалось в голове ... Цель MVP не сделать возможность подмены UI"_ -- вы сказали: _"Представление прячется за интерфейсом IView ... Можно выбросить WinForms и заменить на что угодно"_ -- выбросить и заменить - это подмена. а если  _"нужно менять UI"_, то для чего делать IView и прятать реализацию от Presenter'а? для тестирования UI делить их тоже не надо, т.к. тестирование UI это проверка того как смотрятся шрифты, все ли на месте, нет ли перекосов, нет ли мерцания и т.д. P.S. в WinForms есть биндинги -- пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478676)

Comment: @Stack "подмена UI" не относится к MVP вообще. IView выделяется для того, чтобы можно было подменить инстанс при тестировании. И даже если просто разделять отвественности (забить на тестирование), то код может быть вразных сборках, а циклическая зависимость запрещена. Разумеется смена инстансов это по существу есть "подмена UI". Но это не есть самоцель. Я дополнил пост (тут размер не позволяет)
    
ps: я не говорил что биндингов нет. я говорил, что нет нормальных.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте представим, что надо создать справочник планет Солнечной системы в виде Console Application. Список планет выводится в консоль. Для выбора планеты надо набрать ее порядковый номер и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
В соответствии с описанием паттерна в своей программе надо определить три отдельных класса. При этом Presenter не должен знать как работает View, который по команде Presenter'a, выводит список планет в консоль, а введенный порядковый номер планеты возвращает Presenter'у.
Считается, что такое разделение и сокрытие деталей реализации позволяет сделать части системы заменяемыми. Но это не так.
Представьте, что прошло время, и надо в справочник планет добавить миллионы астероидов, сделать 3D визуализацию движения объектов и реализовать сенсорное управление.
Понятно, что если Model можно дополнить, то Presenter и View придется создавать с нуля, т.к. **UI-логика** совершенно отличается от той, что была в консольном приложении. При этом логика в Model (**бизнес-логика**) никак не меняется и не зависит от UI-логики.

---

Паттерн MVP является производным от MVC (Model-View-Controller), который был представлен в [1979](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B3,_%D0%A2%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B5) г. и назывался Thing-Model-View-Editor. На [сайте](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/~trygver/themes/mvc/mvc-index.html) автора, профессора Реенскауг Трюгве, видно на графике, что Controller и несколько View объединяются в Tool.

---

Графический интерфейс в Windows построен на основе оконной подсистемы - Windows Manager, GDI и DWM. Есть десятки системных функций WinAPI, которые позволяют [управлять окнами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632595(v=vs.85).aspx), [перехватывать события](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) движения мыши и т.д.

В WinForms базовым классом для создания графического интерфейса является [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control).

Если посмотреть на определение MVP, то получается, что раз Control позволяет отображать данные и получать события мыши и т.д., то Control - это и есть View. Но это не так.

Дело в том, что **Control является оберткой** для оконной подсистемы Windows, взаимодействие с которой происходит через вызовы функций Win API (их можно увидеть в [исходниках Control](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs)).

Движение мыши, нажатия клавиш и другие системные события попадают в Message Queue (это очередь системных событий, которые транслируются в вызовы соответствующих методов Control; системные события можно перехватывать, если переопределить метод [WndProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc) или [PreProcessMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.preprocessmessage)).

Получается, что View - это оконная подсистема Windows, а Presenter - это Control.

```
 MVP       :  WinForms приложение 
----------------------------------------------
 Мodel     :  Объекты для работы с данными
----------------------------------------------
 View      :  Оконная подсистема Windows
----------------------------------------------
 Presenter :  Производные от Control
```

Пример на C# с цитатами из определения паттерна MVP.

```
interface IModel {
   int Data { get; set; }
}

class Presenter : TextBox {
   IModel Model;

   public Presenter(IModel m) {
      this.Model = m;   
      var d = m.Data;  // извлекаем данные из модели
      var s = d.ToString(); // форматируем данные для отображения
      this.Text = s;  // передаем в Представление (оконная подсистема Windows).   
   }

   // маршрутизация пользовательских команд
   protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
      base.OnKeyDown(e);
      if (this.Text.Contains("1")) {   // логика
         var d = int.Parse(this.Text); // форматируем данные          
         this.Model.Data = d; // управляем моделью
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете, если бы Вы смогли привести законченный код, который компилируется и запускается, то это можно было бы понять даже начинающему. А так не совсем понятно.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin _"привести законченный код, который компилируется и запускается"_ -- позже добавлю.

Comment: Модель вроде же ни в каких вариация MVC обработкой чьих-либо событий не занимается?

Comment: @Sergey _"Модель вроде же ни в каких вариация MVC обработкой чьих-либо событий не занимается?"_ -- события из view передаются в presenter. в нем происходит обработка события. а дальше presenter управляет моделью. у меня в ответе все так и происходит в примере.

Comment: @Stack Ну я и смотрю табличку в ответе `Мodel     :  Обработчики событий Control и объекты для работы с данными`

Comment: @Sergey _"Ну я и смотрю табличку в ответе"_ -- спасибо. исправил.

Comment: "Считается, что такое разделение и сокрытие деталей реализации позволяет сделать части системы заменяемыми. Но это не так."  - 
нет. основная цель разделить ответственности и возможность тестирования.

Comment: @vitidev _"разделить ответственности и возможность тестирования"_  -- как в вашем примере тестировать Presenter. из-за new в методе `LoadPlanets() { var planets=new PlanetReader()...}` его невозможно тестировать отдельно от конкретной модели.

Comment: @Stack мой пример написан для демонстрации неизменности презентера и модели (как вы и просили, хотя MVP не для этого служит, но зато это пример реализации MVP). Я написал отдельный пост для того, чтобы помочь навести порядок в вашей голове

Comment: @vitidev _"Я написал отдельный пост для того, чтобы помочь навести порядок в вашей голове"_ -- спасибо. вы пишете: _"Допустим нам нужно написать приложение под разные абстрактные платформы"_ -- если надо сделать идентичные приложения на других платформах, то код должен быть максимально переносимым. Вы правы, надо выделить View и менять его при переносе. Но вопрос о конкретной платформе .NET WinForms -- а такие приложения, если и переносят, то на WPF и при этом UI полностью меняют.